# Unable to write PDF to disk. Windows error 5. Access is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I use AbcPdf,.. after I generate the pdf, I want to save it into some folder, for example "generatedPdf"

```
string path  = "C:\\project-name\\wwwroot\\generatedPdf\\";
try{
   theDoc.Save(path);
   theDoc.Clear();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
}
```

the Error message is :

> *Unable to write PDF to disk. Windows error 5. Access is denied.*

For this folder I set permissions for IISUser and SystemUser => full control

what I do wrong?

Comment: don't you need to provide a filename, e.g. `c:\proj\root\genpdf\somefile.pdf`?

Comment: @MarcB Yep you're right! this solve the problem :)

Comment: @MarcB put your Answer, and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a filename:

```
string path  = "C:\\project-name\\wwwroot\\generatedPdf\\somefile.pdf";
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```